# CMake not compile on raspberry

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi

I'm new with cmake.
With cmake I was able to compile my project on my laptop, but on the raspberry is not working.

This is the error i get on raspberry:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.0'
-- Found GLib: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so (found   version "2.42.1") 
-- Found mhd: /usr/include  
CMake Error at cmake/FindGLIB.cmake:39 (add_library): add_library cannot create imported target "glib-2.0" because another target with the same name already exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):librerie/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)

-- Found GLib: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so (found version "2.42.1") 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/pl1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

This is my project structure:

```
src->
---- CMakeLists.txt
---- main.c
---- librerie->
-------------- CMakeLists.txt
-------------- cJSON.c
-------------- cJSON.h
-------------- config.c
-------------- config.h
-------------- server_web.c
-------------- server_web.h
-------------- funzioni_thread.c
-------------- funzioni_thread.h
---- cmake->
-------------- FindGLIB.cmake
-------------- FindMHD.cmake
```

This is First CMakeLists :

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (TestPL)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(GLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(MHD REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory (librerie)
set (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} librerie)

include_directories (${GLib_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EXTRA_LIBS})

# add the executable
add_executable(TestPL main.c)
target_link_libraries (TestPL ${GLib_LIBRARY} ${MHD_LIBRARY} ${EXTRA_LIBS} m)
```

This is CMakeLists in librerie directory:

```
find_package(GLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(MHD REQUIRED)
include_directories (${GLib_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EXTRA_LIBS})

add_library (librerie cJSON.c config.c generic.c server_web.c  funzioni_thread.c)
target_link_libraries (librerie ${GLib_LIBRARY} ${MHD_LIBRARY})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call twice

```
find_package(GLIB REQUIRED)
```

First time it is called from  top-level `CMakeLists.txt` and defines `glib-2.0` target. Second time it is called from `librerie/CMakeLists.txt` and attempt to create `glib-2.0` again. That is why you see that error message: the target is already defined in this scope.

Possible workaround is to step into library subdirectory first, and only then call `find_package()` in top-level *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_subdirectory (librerie)

find_package(GLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(MHD REQUIRED)
```

Because *IMPORTED* targets has local visibility, `glib-2.0` target defined by `find_package(GLIB)` call from subdirectory *librerie/* will not be visible after returning from this subdirectory. So the second call from top-level directory will succeed.

Comment: Thank you very much!! that was the problem, now it works! what I do not understand is why even the wrong way on my laptop runs quietly

Comment: Probably, your laptop has different `FindGLIB.cmake` script, which does not define imported targets but variables instead. Unlike to targets, redefinition of variables is not an error on CMake.

Comment: The FindGLIB.cmake script is the same for raspberry and laptop, I copied all the project files, maybe on arm does things differently?, boh, anyway, thanks again!